# Rails, jQuery fileupload and multiple forms on page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I have a rails app where I want upload documents without page refresh. I followed jQuery fileupload Railscast and got this functionality to work. However, the page where I upload files has many forms for upload and the uploaded file always goes to the top form (e.x.there are 7 forms for uploading, I upload picture via form nr 6 but the file gets uploaded through the first form).

The page with forms is Memberships#index:

```
...    
<div class="tab-pane active" id="all_memberships">
      <%= render 'memberships_table', memberships: @memberships, no_content: I18n.t('tables.memberships.all') %>
    </div>
...
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div class="upload">
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

_memberships.html.erb:

```
...
<%= render 'shared/candidate_req_status', membership: membership  %>
...
```

_candidate_req_status.html.erb:

```
...
<%= render 'shared/candidate_doc_form', req: req %>
...
```

And finally _candidate_doc_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for  req do |f| %>
  <div class="candidate-doc-form">
    <%= f.file_field :candidate_doc, class: 'inline filestyle' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I enable fileuploa from coffee file:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.edit_candidate_requirement_status').each ->
    $(this).fileupload
      dataType: "script"
      add: (e, data) ->
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[0]))
        $('#' + e.target.id).append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      progress: (e, data) ->
        if data.context
          progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
          data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

Any ideas how to correctly upload files with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Milind's way but that didn't change anything. Turns out that a bootstrap addon, [Bootstrap-filestyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/), was messing up the upload. After removing it, everything worked as it should (but my upload buttons don't look so sexy now).

Comment: if you need sexy button and file upload widget - take a look at uploadcare.com

Answer (score 0):

Jquery fileupload works using `formid` with each form having unique id which is used to invoke the fileupload.hence if you are using 7 forms expecting 7 different uploads for each form then,use different js files for each upload..for example if you have **7 form**s,use **7 different js** and form `ids`..

for example:-

in all forms use distinct `ids` for each form...such as

```
 //in form 1
 <%= form_for(@object1,:html=>{:id=>"form_1_upload"}) do |f |%>
.....
....
....

//in form 7
 <%= form_for(@object7,:html=>{:id=>"form_7_upload"}) do |f |%>

        //add other as well as main javascripts to invoke fileupload
       //this to invoke fileupload for form_1 using form_1_upload id
        <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3/form_1.js" %>
        ....
        ....
        ....
          //this to invoke fileupload for form_7 using form_7_upload id
        <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3/form_7.js" %>

in individual js files...**use the form ids** to capture the uploads..

///form_1.js

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#form_1_upload').fileupload({

})

..
..
..


//use the same in all other forms and js
```

...HOPE IT HELPS